# Output text between two patterns on the same line using sed command

Tags: bash, search, sed, replace

I tried this command, but it works only to a certain extent.

Input file content:

```
this is begin not sure what is wrong end and why not
```

Command:

```
cat file | sed 's/.*begin \(.*\)end/\1/'
```

Output:

```
not sure what is wrong and why not
```

Desired output (please see notes below):

```
not sure what is wrong
```

1. My sed command searches for the first pattern and second pattern, but omits the second pattern and prints the text. However, it also prints the rest of the line, `why not`. I do not want to print what comes after the second pattern, only what is between the two patterns. I am not sure how to do this.
2. What if there are two `end` on the same line?

Can someone provide and explain the command?

Comment: You can use `sed 's/.*begin \(.*\) end.*/\1/' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your current input you may use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*begin \(.*\) end.*/\1/' file
```

```
not sure what is wrong
```

Difference is use of `.*` after `end` that matches text after last `end` and discards in substitution.

---

However for your 2nd part if there are two `end` words, `sed` command won't work correctly as it will find last `end` due to **greedy matching** of `.*`.

e.g if your input is:

```
this is begin not sure what is wrong end and why not end
```

Then following `awk` would work better:

```
awk -F 'begin | end' '{print $2}' file
```

```
not sure what is wrong
```

Comment: thx - both work - thx for reading the entire thread before answeing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only substituting what was matched, not the other text after `end`.  Just add a `.*`:

```
txt='this is begin not sure what is wrong end and why not'

sed 's/.*begin \(.*\)end.*/\1/' <<< "$txt"
```

Gives:

```
not sure what is wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `sed` may help you on same.

```
echo "this is begin not sure what is wrong end and why not" | sed 's/.*begin //;s/ end.*//'
```